# Padding right when container wider than screen?

Tags: html, css, screen

I have the following html tree:

- div with `padding: 2rem 1.25rem;`

  - div with `max-width: none` so that it overflows past the screen's width

The padding is applied correctly on the top, bottom and left side, but not on the right.

[image: Html Tree Screenshot]

I know what's the problem but I'm not sure how to solve it. The parent div has a width of `375px`, which is the screen's width, whereas the child div has `890px`. How can I make the parent expand like the child?

There are a few other ancestors for the parent div above. Do I need to make all of them expand?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .parent {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      padding: 2rem 1.25rem;
    }
    
    .child {
      background-color: #f5f8ff;
      border: 1px solid #eff5f5;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      min-width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .item {
      align-items: center;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 44px;
      width: 256px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     <div class="item">Foo</div>
     <div class="item">Bar</div>
     <div class="item">Baz</div>
     <div class="item">Qux</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add a snippet of your code?

Comment: @HaldenCollier sorry, lemme do it now

Comment: Just added it now

Comment: No worries. Was your question answered below, or are you still stuck?

Comment: Unfortunately no because the parent div is a flex box.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very vague but if you want your parent div to just basically always be just big enough to house your child div. You can try setting your parent div to display: inline.

```
.parentdiv{
 display: inline;
 }
```

And by not setting a width. The parent div will always just be big enough to hold its children divs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And yes if the parent div has a parent div also. It may need to have the same principals applied.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .parent {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      padding: 2rem 1.25rem;
    }
    
    .child {
      background-color: #f5f8ff;
      border: 1px solid #eff5f5;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      min-width: 100%;
    }
    
    .item {
      text-align: center;
      flex: 0 0 25%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     <div class="item">Foo</div>
     <div class="item">Bar</div>
     <div class="item">Baz</div>
     <div class="item">Qux</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is nice, but unfortunately setting `flex-basis` to 25% invalidates my initial use case, which is having a child div that expands **beyond** the screen's width.

Comment: You want the child div to expand beyond? In that case, I need a bit more of an explanation. Could you post a screenshot of a sketch showing what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Make the parent have this CSS `display: inline-flex;` rather than just being `display: flex;`